# groupby two columns based on third column values

Tags: python, group-by, jupyter-notebook, timestamp

I have a dataset like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '11:20', '13:30', '15:20', '17:12', '16:00', '8:20'],
           'item': [coffee, bread, pizza, rice, soup, coffee, bread, pizza, rice, soup]})
```

I want to produce this output
[image]

first need to split time into 3 categories, based on these intervals
interval (6,11] for breakfast, (11,15] for lunch and (15,20] for dinner.

this is my code:

```
df['hour'] = df.Time.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
def time_period(hour):
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 11:
        return 'breakfast'
    elif hour >= 11 and hour < 15:
        return 'lunch'
    else:
        return 'dinner'
df['meal'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda x: time_period(x))
```

but I don't know how to do 'groupby' part.

Comment: Do not open the same question more the one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply groupby on "meal" and create list of items for each "meal". Just add the following line to do this-

`df.groupby(['meal'])["item"].apply(list)`

You can apply count and all on top of this to achieve the result you want.